# What USB Modem to buy?

Tags: usb, hardware, modem

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed. On a Dell latitude D520 laptop. I need to buy a USB modem as the onboard one was not detected and I have fussed around long enough trying to get it working.

What make/model do you suggest for a USB modem that's easy to use?

Comment: Do you mean a modem, or a USB wifi-dongle?

Comment: Dial up modem via USB. US robotics makes a popular one. Parents only have Dial-up at their summer home.

Comment: I found this anyone install this before?  http://ubuntu-wireless-usb.computers-city.com/2011/10/14/ubuntu-wireless-usb-trendnet-56k-usb-2-0-phone-internet-and-fax-modem-tfm-561u-white/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware recommendation is off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware recommendation is off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for hardware shopping recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

The [US Robotics 56K USB FAX/MODEM](http://www.usr.com/products/modem/modem-product.asp?sku=USR5637) works great.

[image: US Robotics 56K FAX/MODEM]