# Help with Dial Up

Tags: drivers, internet, modem, wvdial

I am trying to set up a computer for my friend that has dial up.
The problem is nothing I try can detect the modem. GnomePPP can't find it and I can't figure Kppp out.  I've been looking all over the net on my ethernet trying to find an answer but I keep getting routed back [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto)
I have also tried using scanModem and it finds something like

`Conexant Systems, Inc. HCF 56k Data/Fax/Voice Modem`

but the rest of it is really confusing.

I've also tried [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1903439) but I'm not very terminal savvy and it didn't work.
It seems like I have to compile a driver but I don't know which one or how to do it.

I have also tried multiple modems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

***EDIT:***
  scanModem thinks the modem is disabled on startup.

***EDIT:***
I reinstalled Ubuntu but the problem persists.

Comment: Yeah - that's a "winmodem" or software modem. Try a USR: http://askubuntu.com/questions/85445/what-usb-modem-to-buy

Comment: Would [this modem](http://www.usr.com/support/overview-template.asp?prod=s-cour) work?

Comment: Yes! That's a "real" modem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got a USR Courier V.Everything Modem on Craigslist.
Plugged it in and BAM Wvdial detected it.  From all my research and what other people have said, it appears that Ubuntu doesn't have much support for internal modems.

My Courier is connected via a serial cable but a usb modem should work too.

***UPDATE:*** Just realized I forgot to  update after I tested it.  I could get it to call a phone, but when I tried connecting to copper.net it didn't work.  I think its because they don't support Linux, but I'm not sure.

Ultimately I guess dial up is not for the timid on Ubuntu.

Links
[US Robotics USB external modem](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0013FDLM0)

[What USB Modem to buy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85445/what-usb-modem-to-buy)